# Images go out of the Text Width?

Tags: graphics, floats, horizontal-alignment, subfloats

I will try to put six images to same row. But my image goes beyond textline width. I need some expert help to resolve this.

```
    \begin{figure}[!htb]
  \makebox[\textwidth]{
   \begin{minipage}{0.16\textwidth}
     \centering
     \includegraphics[width=50mm]{420}
     \textbf{420}
   \end{minipage}\hfill
   \begin{minipage}{0.16\textwidth}
     \centering
     \includegraphics[width=50mm,scale=0.5]{421}
     \textbf{421}
   \end{minipage}\hfill
     \begin{minipage}{0.16\textwidth}
     \centering
     \includegraphics[width=50mm,scale=0.5]{422}
    \textbf{422}
   \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}{0.16\textwidth}
     \centering
     \includegraphics[width=50mm,scale=0.5]{423}
    \textbf{423}
   \end{minipage}\hfill
   \begin{minipage}{0.16\textwidth}
     \centering
     \includegraphics[width=50mm,scale=0.5]{424}
    \textbf{424}
   \end{minipage}\hfill
     \begin{minipage}{0.16\textwidth}
     \centering
     \includegraphics[width=50mm,scale=0.5]{425}
     \textbf{425}
   \end{minipage}
   }
\end{figure}
```

this is out put recived me .

[image]

Comment: Drop the scale and set their widths to `\linewidth` to match the width of he minipage container. What is the purpose of that makebox? Probably also better to have the minipage width be slightly smaller

Comment: Since you have six images with `width=50mm`, their combined width would be at least `30cm` -- far too much for any "normal" paper dimension, e.g., A4 or US Letter.

Comment: @daleif yep , that ,makebow i try to put insdie frame , but it is not work.  i am using A4 paper

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some comments and suggestions:

- When typesetting images using the `\includegraphics` instruction, it's usually not a good idea to use absolute size instructions, such as `width=50mm`, or a dimension that's a function of the original image size, such as `scale=0.5`. (For sure, *never* use both a fixed absolute width and a `scale` option.) It's a really good idea, instead, to set the image width to a fraction of the width of the enclosing `minipage`; quite often, setting `width=1\textsize`, i.e., setting the two widths equal, is just fine.
- Do change the widths of the 6 `minipage` environments from `0.16\textwidth` to `0.16\linewidth`. Making this change doesn't matter if the document employs a single-column layout. However, it does matter if you were using a two- or multi-column setup. By employing `\linewidth`, you're future-proofing your document should you ever have to recompile it using a two-column layout.
- I would further like to suggest that you load the `subcaption` package, which provides an environment called `subfigure`, and employ 6 `subfigure` environments instead of the 6 `minipage` environments. A `subfigure` environment *is*, for all intents and purposes, a `minipage` environments that "knows" what to do with `\caption` and `\caption*` statements. (`\caption*` directives do not create an arabic or letter number to go with the caption text.)
- Finally, do also get rid of the `\makebox` instruction, which doesn't do anything useful anyway, and of all 6 `\centering` instructions, since they are now redundant.

[image]

```
\documentclass[demo]{article} % remove 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!htb]
\captionsetup[subfigure]{font=bf} % is this really needed?
\begin{subfigure}{0.16\linewidth}  
   \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{420}
   \caption*{420}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.16\linewidth} 
   \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{421}
   \caption*{421}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.16\linewidth}
   \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{422}
   \caption*{422}
\end{subfigure}\hfill % <-- this '\hfill' instance was missing in the OP's code
\begin{subfigure}{0.16\linewidth}
   \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{423}
   \caption*{423}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.16\linewidth}
   \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{424}
   \caption*{424}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.16\linewidth}
   \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{425}
   \caption*{425}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: this is actualy , what am  needed. Thank you soo much. explain the answer very cleary relly help full.

Comment: Isn't ``\linewidth` better to use here? Then the user does not have tow wrap their head around `\textwidth` meaning two diffrent things. I think it better for users to see `\textwidth` as something static to the document.

Comment: @daleif - Thanks. The distinction between `\linewidth` and `\textwidth` doesn't matter in a single-column document setup, for which `\linewidth` and `\textwidth` are initially the same. It does matter, though, for two- and multi-column setups. Just to cover all the bases, I've changed the code to make the widths of the `minipage` environments a fraction of `\linewidth` and created a new bullet point in the text to draw attention to this distinction.

Comment: @Mico I would have done it the other way round. Remember that `\linewidth` also changes inside lists.

Comment: @daleif - I'm not sure I follow you. If (a big if!) a figure-like environment were stuck inside the a list-like environment, wouldn't you still want to use (the now somewhat reduced value of) `\linewidth` that corresponds to the current list level in the calculations of the `minipage` environments?

Comment: I would make the subfigure width in terms of `\textwidth` and make the width of the gfx in terms of `\linewidth`. As it is now it is hard for a normal user to get their head around what changes when. I think it is better to have the user see `\linewidth` as the `current effective` line width (even if that might not always be true).

Comment: @daleif -- (By the way, I find this conversation *really helpful* for clarifying my own understanding of these parameters.) Unless I'm badly mistaken, the suggestion to use `\textwidth` for the "outer" calculations and `\linewidth` for the inner (admittedly trivially easy) calculations, *fails* in a two-column layout, which sets `\linewidth=\columnwidth` and `\textwidth=2\columnwidth+\columnsep`. Of course, your suggestion could be salvaged easily by using `\columnwidth` instead of `\textwidth` in the "outer" calculations.

Comment: Me as well, I was surprised that textwidth changes inside minipage and not just linewidth (eating lunch so not at pc). I don't see much of a problem in says to users: if you're in a twocolumn setup use columnwidth instead of textwidth. I'd say the vast majority is in one column mode